# How to make time picker to show only 24 hour time format in android

Tags: android

Please can any one tell me how to make a time picker to show only 24 hour time format.This is my current code.But i am getting both 24 and 12 hour formats.But i need only 24 hour format.

{

```
booktime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(Book_A_Table.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                        booktime.setText( selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                    }
                }, hour, minute,true);//Yes 24 hour time
                mTimePicker.setTitle("Select Time");
                mTimePicker.show();
            }
        });
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true); 

//Boolean: true to display in 24-hour mode, false for 12-hour mode with AM/PM
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest pramod,But i have tried that but it is showing both 24 and 12 hour formats.But i need only 24 hour format.

Answer (score 0):

[image: timepickerdialog]

```
TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int minute) {

            //code here
            }
        }, cHour, cMin, true);
```

true at the end is for setting the dialog to 24hr format, on the attached pic the inner part is for day and outer for night.